# Problems ordering character matrixs with R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

First of all, sorry for my english, it's not my mother lenguage.

I have a character matrix like this.

```
L4 JUAN 6 1.345

L4 PEPE 8 1.5678

L4 JULIA 4 3.156
```

I'd like to order the matrix by the third column. But the matrix is a character matrix and I don't know how to transform it to a data.frame and order it properly.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option. Notice that it is important to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to avoid creating factor when converting to a data frame. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Concert to data frame
dt <- as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Order by the third column
dt2 <- dt[order(dt[, 3]), ]

dt2
#   V1    V2 V3     V4
# 3 L4 JULIA  4  3.156
# 1 L4  JUAN  6  1.345
# 2 L4  PEPE  8 1.5678
```

**DATA**

```
m <- matrix(c("L4", "JUAN", "6", "1.345", "L4", "PEPE", "8", "1.5678", "L4", "JULIA", "4", "3.156"),
            ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below

```
m <- matrix(c("L4", "JUAN", "6", "1.345",
"L4", "PEPE",  "8",  "1.5678",
"L4", "JULIA", "4", "3.156"), nrow = 3, byrow = T)
df <- as.data.frame(m)
df$V3 <- as.integer(df$V3)
df <- df[order(df$V3), ]
```

Comment: Good idea but it is not working. This is because `as.integer` convert the factor level to numbers. By doing that you changed the value in `V3`. Please use `as.integer(as.character(df$V3))`. Or like what I proposed in my answer, setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when using `as.data.frame`.